# Conversion of time zone in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing a conversion of timezone from current_timestamp to 'US/Eastern' in snowflake view. I was able to create the view but when I preview the data I am getting Timestamp 'US/Eastern' is not recognized error.

I am converting like below:

`((CONVERT_TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'US/Eastern') - INTERVAL  '5 HOUR'))`

Comment: [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) supports standard iana.org time zones: America/Los_Angeles, Europe/London, UTC, Etc/GMT, etc. However, certain simple time zones, such as PDT, are not currently supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus looking at [TIMEZONE doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html)'s LukStorms points, and following the link to the Wikipedia [List_of_tz_database_time_zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) `US/Eastern` is the same as `America/New_York`, thus

```
((CONVERT_TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York') - INTERVAL  '5 HOUR'))
```

But the 2 parameter version is in the form:

```
CONVERT_TIMEZONE( <target_tz> , <source_timestamp> )
```

but you are doing `( <source_timestamp>, <target_tz>)`

Also the `- INTERVAL  '5 HOUR'` appears the same as "to UTC for the current not in Daylight savings time", it would seem safer to use the complete version of `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` to do the to `UTC` part.
it would seem you should use the form from the examples:

```
-- Convert a "wallclock" time in Warsaw to the matching "wallclock" time in UTC

select convert_timezone('Europe/Warsaw', 'UTC', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp_ntz) as conv;
```

thus use :

```
convert_timezone('America/New_York', 'UTC', current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz)
```